# 'List other names used section on Passport Renewal form' must include married names?

Tags: passport-renewals

My US passport matches my Drivers License, Birth Certificate, SSN. When filling out renewal form ds82,  question 9A, nothing has changed from the last passport but it asks for other names used. Must I include both previously married names, especially when there are no changes from previous passport? The current passport simply expired.

Answer (score 5):

> Must I include both previously married names, especially when there are no changes from previous passport?

Yes.  The question asks for you to

> List all other names you have used. (Examples: Birth Name, Maiden, Previous Marriage, Legal Name Change. Attach additional pages if needed)

It does not say "other names you have used since your previous passport was issued."  It does not say "other names you've used but haven't mentioned before."  You should include every name you have ever used other than your current name.